# Use registry tweak to change the duration of the welcome screen

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-registry, login-screen

I found a registry tweak that has been used since Win XP. It seems to be used on Network machines.

I tried it on both my Win 7 and win 8.1 and did not work on either one. I have home edition windows.

The tweak is suppose to increase or decrease the welcome screen duration at login.

The String is called "DelayedDesktopSwitchTimeout"

Explanation about this tweak @: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/940452/the-welcome-screen-may-be-displayed-for-30-seconds-and-the-logon-scrip

I need to know how to get it to work or something similar to it.

I am trying to increase the duration of the welcome screen so the programs are loaded by the time the welcome screen ends.

I require that for security reasons.

There are similar questions in the forum but did not help me.